# Detect 2 spaces in whole string(sentence) with regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to detect if the sentence has more than ONE space:
"one space" => false
"two or more spaces inside" => true

I have such regex `/\s\s+/g` but it doesn't seem correct as it detects two spaces in a row but not in the whole provided string. How can I find more then ONE space in WHOLE string?

Comment: You could do it like this `.*\s.*\s` but note that `\s` can also match a newline. Instead it might be `.*[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n]`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

An option could be matching 2 times from the start of the string as least as possible chars followed by a whitespace char without a newline.

```
^.*?[^\S\r\n].*?[^\S\r\n]
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `[^\S\r\n]` Match a whitespace without a newline using [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `[^\S\r\n]` Match a whitespace without a newline

```js
[" a b", "a b ", " aa ", "    b", " a", "b "]
.forEach(s => console.log(`"${s}" --> ${/^.*?[^\S\r\n].*?[^\S\r\n]/.test(s)}`))
```

You might also for example match all whitespace chars using `\s` and then check if the number of matches is greater than 1.

```js
[" a b", "a b ", " aa ", "    b", " a", "b "]
.forEach(s => console.log(`"${s}" --> ${s.match(/\s/g).length > 1}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
.*\s.*\s.*
```

The `.*` matches 0 or more characters (any of them).

Comment: You can omit the last `.*` as it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

"More than one" can be rephrased as "at least two":

```js
^(?:\S*\s){2}    // any two whitespace chars
^(?:[^ ]* ){2}   // any two regular space chars
```

You may change `2` with any other number to require at least X space/whitesapce chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hl9bV2/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\s` - a whitespace char
- `){2}` - end of the group, repeat twice.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
["one space", "two or more spaces inside"].forEach(x =>
  console.log(x, '=>', /^(?:\S*\s){2}/.test(x))
)
```